# Let $\mathbb{C^*}=\mathbb{C}- \{0\} $ denote the group of non-zero complex numbers under multiplication.

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $Y_n=\{z\in\mathbb{C} :z^n =1 ,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ . Which of the following is(are) subgroup(s) of $\mathbb{C^*}$ ?

(a) $\cup_{n=1}^{100} Y_n$

(b) $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} Y_{2^n}$

(c) $\cup_{n=100}^{\infty} Y_n$

(d) $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} Y_n$

I am unable to think anything here, as they are unions . I think , we can not apply subgroup test here.

Comment: Which of the unions are closed under multiplication?

Comment: Yes, (b),(c),(d). Can you give an example to show that (a) fails?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj If, by subgroup test, you mean that the  given set is closed under multiplication, inverse, and contains the identity, then it works regardless of whether the given set was a union/intersection of some other sets or not.

Comment: I, think $Y_n$ is a group of $n^{th}$ roots of unity under multiplication. But I'm not getting anything from here. @quasi

Comment: @quasi $ab$ satisfies $ab^{mn}=1$ ,and least value will be $1$. Isn't it ?

Comment: If $a$ satisfies $a^m=1$, for some $m$, and $b$ satisfies  $b^n=1$, for some $n$, then $ab$ satisfies $(ab)^k=1$, for some $k$. What's an obvious value of $k$?

Comment: If $a^3=1$, and $b^5=1$, and if the exponents $3,5$ are least for $a,b$, respectively, then the least $k$ such that $(ab)^k=1$ is $k=(3)(5)=15$. But if instead, we have $a^4=1$, and $b^6=1$, we can do better than $k=(4)(6)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously $$1\in Y_n$$for any $n\in\Bbb N$ which ensures existence of identity in all the unions. Also associativity holds and we have$$z\in Y_n\to z^n=1\to \dfrac{1}{z^n}=\left(\dfrac{1}{z}\right)^n=1\to \dfrac{1}{z}\in Y_n$$which implies on existence of inverse. Therefore we only need to show the closure.

> a

Take $z_1\in Y_{89}$ and $z_2\in Y_{97}$ therefore there doesn't exist and $n\le 100$ for which $$z_1z_2\in Y_n$$in fact the smallest such $n$ is $89\times 97$ which is greater that $100$ therefore part a is not a subgroup.

> b

for $m<n$ we have $$Y_{2^m}\subset Y_{2^n}$$(why?) therefore this part is a subgroup.

> c and d

a similar argument as of b holds and then we have that both are subgroups.